# How do I substring values in two columns to a new column and change the order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns with varchar data. I need to create a new column with a new ID composed from both columns, the order needs to change and I need to remove the hyphen.

```
ID1            | ID2       |
---------------+-----------
011216         | 313501-16 |
011280         | 313501-18 |
011283         | 313501-19 |
```

For example the first record needs to look like:

```
01121616313501
```

I've tried adding a new column to my existing table:

```
alter table Customers add CustID INT;

update Customers
    set CustID = cast(SUBSTRING(ID, 5, 4) as numeric);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the leading zeros you should define the column as `VARCHAR` and not `INTEGER`.

```
alter table Customers add CustID varchar(15);

update Customers
set CustID = ID1 + right(ID2, 2) + left(ID2, 6);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a95ebf4993bb2effa7c1d8ffbb043a3).
Results:

```
> ID1    | ID2       | CustID        
> :----- | :-------- | :-------------
> 011216 | 313501-16 | 01121616313501
> 011280 | 313501-18 | 01128018313501
> 011283 | 313501-19 | 01128319313501
```

Comment: Good point. I didn't notice the leading 0 in the example. Of course, that's not ideal for an `ID` column. What I would recommend if it were me would be to convert to an `integer`, but to use `CAST(CONCAT(IIF(ID1<100000,'100','10'),ID1,SUBSTRING(ID2,1,5)) as numeric)` to keep the order of things, but not end up with a leading `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
   UPDATE Customers 
   SET CustID = CAST(CONCAT(ID1,SUBSTRING(ID2,1,5),SUBSTRING(ID2,8,2)) as numeric)
```

I think I got the character counts right, but I didn't try this myself yet.

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that you are not asking for the numbers after the dash, so the new ID would simply be:

```sql
   UPDATE Customers SET CustID = CAST(CONCAT(ID1,SUBSTRING(ID2,1,5)) as numeric)
```